# Dimension too large, <to be read again> error

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, geogebra

I've been using GeoGebra for drawing some figures for a while now, since I'm totally new to TikZ. Up to now I'm fine with the figures I created with GeoGebra, although the code is awfully complicated. This time, however, I've got an error I can't solve.

The error message reads:

```
Dimension too large.

<to be read again>

   \relax

l.34 \end{axis}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet. Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

Although I get that message I can see the plot, which is shown here:

[image]

My (complicated) code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale = 1.2, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1.129485186780251,
xmax=5.72744433329757,
ymin=-0.96997054991852,
ymax=5.616499082403562,
xtick={0.0},
ytick={0.0}, restrict y to domain=-0.96997054991852:5.616499082403562,]
\clip(-1.129485186780251,-0.76997054991852) rectangle (5.82744433329757,5.916499082403562);
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.129485186780251:10.42744433329757] plot(\x,{(\x)-2.25E-50});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.129485186780251:10.42744433329757] plot(\x,{0-0.07123888916965247*(\x)^(4.0)+1.5096421986752417*(\x)^(3.0)-9.579592272284225*(\x)^(2.0)+23.93776936035761*(\x)-17.586966972004486});
\draw (5.196549774492815,0.49322601353710884) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw (0.020629571335991016,5.575885328535428) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)$};
\draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.5,1.5)-- (1.5,0.);
\draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (3.,0.)-- (3.,3.);
\draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (4.5,4.5)-- (4.501485877435332,0.);
\draw (1.2137496293807978,0.021729881572188525) node[anchor=north west] {$x_0$};
\draw (2.700437452518166,0.021729881572188525) node[anchor=north west] {$x_1$};
\draw (4.228710949030006,0.021729881572188525) node[anchor=north west] {$x_2$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (1.5,1.5) circle (1.2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (4.5,4.5) circle (1.2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (3.,3.) circle (1.2pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There've been users reporting similar error messages. Sometimes adding `restrict y to domain`seemed to have solved the problem, but in my case, it seems like it does not. Can anyone help solving my problem?

Comment: Without testing: in the `axis` environment there are only plain Ti*k*Z commands. What is the purpose of this? That is, what do you need the `axis` for here?

Comment: @Dunno: I added a figure that shows how it should look like. I guess, looking at the picture, that I need the ```axis``` environment.

Comment: Well, the desired output is a graph of a simple cubic function. You do not need any of the mess to produce it. Actually, producing it that way completely defeats the purpose of pgfplots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO GeoCobra is a tool that is not to be used to draw graphs. If you want to plot a function, `pgfplots`, which you load, is appropriate, but not all the output from some black box that you do not understand, and which produces these errors. Rather, you can just plot the function, let Ti*k*Z find the intersections and so on.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:5,axis lines=middle,ymin=-1,ymax=6,xticklabels={},
yticklabels={},xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$f(x)$}]
 \addplot[no marks,smooth,name path=curve]{0.5*(x-2)^3-0.5*(x-2)^2+2.25};
 \addplot[no marks,name path=line]{x};
 \path (0,0) coordinate (O);
 \draw[dashed,name intersections={of=curve and line,total=\t}]
 foreach \X in {1,...,\t} {(intersection-\X) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{}
 -- (intersection-\X|-O) node[below]{$x_{\the\numexpr\X-1}$}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So this is not a real answer to your question in the technical sense, but an attempt to convince you not to use stuff like GeoCobra for something where alternatives exist which allow you to solve the problems systematically.

Comment: GeoCobra seems a funny typo for GeoGebra

Comment: @Dunno: Thank you for the answer! I guess it just takes some time to really learn TikZ. Just a short question on your proposal: Those small vertical lines on the x-axis (horizontal lines on the y-axis): how can I remove them?

Comment: @offline Use `\begin{axis}[domain=0:5,axis lines=middle,ymin=-1,ymax=6,xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$f(x)$}]`, i.e. `xtick=\empty`.

Answer (score 2):

## Motivation

The current accepted answer doesn't explain why

- `Dimension too large`
- `restrict y to domain` doesn't work in OP's example.

Moreover, it mainly relies on hard-coding to chop the curve's `x domain` (that I simply call "`domain`" for the rest of this paragraph).  We have to view the graph first (in a visual/analytical way) before being able to choose a suitable `domain`.  A (polynomial/exponential) curve can increase/decrease rapidly on the right/left part of the whole graph.  It's not trivial to instruct a machine to automatically crop a suitable `domain`.

## Discussion

I'll analyse the error in three parts:

1. minimum problematic example (MPE)
2. maximum PGF dimensions
3. brief explanation about `restrict y to domain`

### MPE

Most of the lines in the generated TikZ code is good.  In other words, those correct lines can be discarded without affecting the error message.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-5,
  xmax=13.6,
  ymin=-5,
  ymax=6.55,
]
  \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (13.6,6.55);
  \draw (-4.9,-4.9) rectangle (13.3,6.5);
  \draw[domain=-5:13.6] plot (\x,{1/2*(\x)^3-2*\x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some minor differences between my MPE and your code:

- `\documentclass` is `standalone` instead of `article` to zoom into the picture and remove the unnecessary surrounding whitespace.
- `compat=1.18` instead of `compat=1.15` as my PDFLaTeX suggests.
- numbers rounded to two decimal places for easier reading.
- I've taken away `restrict y to domain={...}` here.  Even though you add that back to my MPE, the compiler will give the same error.  I'll elaborate on that in the last subsection of this section.
- I've removed `x=1cm` and `y=1cm` in both `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\begin{axis}`, but that's fine since those are the default values in TikZ and PGF Plots.

I'll leave the visual output of

```
pdftoppm -png graph.pdf > graph.png
```

to the next subsection.

At this point, we see that **this question is not about [geogebra](/questions/tagged/geogebra)**, because the above MPE can be constructed without the Geometry suite.

### Maximum PGF dimensions

The [accepted answer of a relevant question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563848/126386) `\usepgflibrary{fpu}` to show that `600cm` is greater than `\maxdimen`, which is the greatest possible value of TeX-dimensions.  `\maxdimen` is `(2^14-2e-5)pt = 16383.99998pt`, but `600cm` is greater than `17000pt`, so using `600cm` as a length would trigger the error `Dimension too large`.

[image: TikZ cubic curve]

The given cubic curve is defined as *y* = *x*³/2 - 2*x* on [-5,13.6].  When *x* = 13, *y* = 1072.5 > 600.  Since `x=1cm` and `y=1cm` by default, when the *y*-coordinate `1072.5cm` is converted to `pt`, it will exceed `\maxdimen`, causing the error.

#### brief explanation about `restrict y to domain`

The key is found in (section 4.22 *Skipping or changing coordinates – filters* of) PGF Plots manual, but not in TikZ manual.  I tried putting this behind `\draw[]`, the system didn't recognize the key `/tikz/restrict y to domain`.  I also tried putting this behind `plot`, but that didn't help, becuase `\draw` is a TikZ command instead of a PGF Plots one.

When you put `restrict y to domain` inside `\begin{axis}`, this PGF Plots key   will be applied to every `\addplot` (or `\addplot+`) inside this `axis` environment, but not on `\draw` elements.

## Solution

I'll first solve my simpler problem, before actually solving yours.

### MPE

Convert `\draw[domain={...}] plot (\x,{...});` into `\addplot[domain={...}] (x,{...});`.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-5,
  xmax=13.6,
  ymin=-5,
  ymax=6.55,
  restrict y to domain=-5:6.55,
]
  \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (13.6,6.55);
  \draw (-4.9,-4.9) rectangle (13.3,6.5);
  \addplot[domain=-5:13.6] (x,{1/2*(x)^3-2*x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ cubic curve restrict y to domain]

The limit isn't fully used, but at least the compiler is no longer complaining.

To stretch the curve, I found that `[3*ymin,3*ymax]` is a suitable `y domain`.  I don't know that the scaling factor `2` doesn't work here.

[image: PGF Plots cubic curve with relaxed restriction]

This approach is much easier to program: you can (regex) search for the occurrence of `\begin{axis}[`, then inject the line "`restrict y to domain=xxx:yyy`".  You can develop your function to calculate the upper and lower limits `xxx` and `yyy` from `ymin` and `ymax`, whose numerical values can be programmatically extracted.  For example, I've simply multiplied both numbers by `3`.

### Original example

I only changed two lines of your code containing `\draw [...] plot (\x,{...})` to `\addplot [...] (x,{...})` with `\x` replaced by `x` without touching what's inside the square bracket `[...]`.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale = 1.2, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1.129485186780251,
xmax=5.72744433329757,
ymin=-0.96997054991852,
ymax=5.616499082403562,
xtick={0.0},
ytick={0.0}, restrict y to domain=-0.96997054991852:5.616499082403562,]
\clip(-1.129485186780251,-0.76997054991852) rectangle (5.82744433329757,5.916499082403562);
\addplot[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.129485186780251:10.42744433329757] (x,{(x)-2.25E-50});
\addplot[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.129485186780251:10.42744433329757] (x,{0-0.07123888916965247*(x)^(4.0)+1.5096421986752417*(x)^(3.0)-9.579592272284225*(x)^(2.0)+23.93776936035761*(x)-17.586966972004486});
\draw (5.196549774492815,0.49322601353710884) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw (0.020629571335991016,5.575885328535428) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)$};
\draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.5,1.5)-- (1.5,0.);
\draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (3.,0.)-- (3.,3.);
\draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (4.5,4.5)-- (4.501485877435332,0.);
\draw (1.2137496293807978,0.021729881572188525) node[anchor=north west] {$x_0$};
\draw (2.700437452518166,0.021729881572188525) node[anchor=north west] {$x_1$};
\draw (4.228710949030006,0.021729881572188525) node[anchor=north west] {$x_2$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (1.5,1.5) circle (1.2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (4.5,4.5) circle (1.2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (3.,3.) circle (1.2pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Observe that your graph is very small in the middle.

[image]

## TODO

Time to work on some string manipulations to:

1. [round every decimal to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41716722/3184351) if necessary
2. replace `[10pt]{article}` to `{standalone}` to make the output image larger.
3. inject the `restrict y domain={...},` to avoid `Dimensions too large`.